# $# positional parameters of what

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script in my code.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu
[ $# -eq 1 ] || exit 1
[ "$1" = "wlanX" ] || exit 2
[ "$PATH" = "/path1:/path2" ] || exit 3
exit 0
```

I read that `$#` counts the number of positional parameters. But my question is positional parameters of what ? I am tyring to figure out what the above code means?

Comment: IMHO it is parameter passed to a script which `$#` takes care of.

Comment: You could check this link once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36007240/what-is-the-use-of-in-bash is this helps you too.